# Rails Paperclip : Is there any option to save the uploaded file outside of the public folder?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip gem for uploading. And i want to save the uploaded file/image outside of the public folder. If you have any idea please share.

Comment: Give the path as `:path => ":rails_root/
uploaded/:attachable_type/:attachable_id/:id_:style.:extension"`

Comment: @Pavan - Why not an answer? :)

Comment: @BroiSatse Just not sure whether it is correct or not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is many. The 'public' option is just to be able to test easily. For your production server, paperclip gives three options:

- File Storage
- [S3 Storage](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) (via aws-sdk)
- Fog Storage

File storage can be configured to go to any folder you want with something like:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {    
  :path => "/yourfolder/:basename.:extension"
}
```

This can be overridden on the class itself if needed:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
  :path => "/yourotherfolder/:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: Hi @ArupRakshit. Not sure I understood your comment. I tried to show both ways (config + in the Model). Anything incorrect here?

Comment: No,, I just comment, to tell what we use..you are correct.