# Paperclip - files outside of the application folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

my paperclip config is:

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar,
                            :path => "/nas/avatars/:id/:style/:id.:extension",
                            :url  => "/system/:id/:style/:id.:extension",
                            :styles => { :profile => "100x100", :thumb => "64x64" }
```

and I try to show it by:

```
image_tag @profile.avatar.url(:profile)
```

But it returns /system/54995fec7061762375100000/profile/54995fec7061762375100000.jpg 404 Not found

Is it possible to physically save files outside of the application folder (mounted NAS)?

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950986/rails-paperclip-is-there-any-option-to-save-the-uploaded-file-outside-of-the-p?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, but you need to serve this files somehow, as they are not inside `public` directory. One way (which I use) is to create a separate controller for that. Something like:

```
def show
    send_file @profile.avatar.path(:profile), type: 'image/jpeg', disposition: 'inline'
end
```

You can also try with symlinks but I don't know how it would work.